# Problem making shooting follows an actor/object

Tags: movement, unreal-4

At first I created an actor to be a projectile, he acts with a simple projectile. When generated it goes straight, anyway...

To do this, I added the **Projectile Movement** component.

It turns out that I wish this projectile did not go straight ahead simply, I would like it to be generated when it came to a minion.

Then my problems began, because being simply an actor, it seems that he can not move with the **Simple Move to Actor/Location** function.

**I created 3 sockets:**

[image]

One for each shot/projectile I was going to test.

**Shooter Blueprint:**

[image]

The **Event Atirar** causes the 3 shots/projectiles I created to be generated (TiroActor, TiroCharacter and TiroPawn).

**TiroActor Blueprint:**

[image]

**TiroCharacter Blueprint:**

[image]

**TiroPawn Blueprint:**

[image]

**I wish that when they were generated, they would go towards the only existing minion in the game, but this does not happen:**

[image]

The **Tiro Actor** goes straight, and nothing makes it stop (I activated the "call in editor" option for the **Event Andar**, but it does not match).

**The Tiro Character falls to the ground and does nothing, but corresponds when I call the Event Andar manually:**

[image]

The **Tiro Pawn** is not even generated...

I modified the "Auto Posses AI" option of **Tiro Character** and **Tiro Pawn** to **Placed in World or Spawned**.

I removed the gravity of all the components of the **Tiro Character**, but even so when generated it falls to the ground.

I would like to know how to make an object (be it actor, pawn or character) when it is generated follow the target (in this case a minion) until it collides with it.

---

**EDIT 1 (complement)**

If it was difficult to understand, I'd like to know how to do something like an AA from a Clash of Clans archer, even a champion AA that attacks from a distance, whether from Dota or LOL.

The projectile of the Dota/LOL tower would be a good example. A guided missile too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chosen code was **TiroActor**. This is because it is the simplest (cause less impact on performance) and supplies all needs.

I took out the other two shots (TiroPawn and TiroCharacter).

**Event Shoot (Shooter Blueprint):**

[image]

As I suspected, it did not make sense to use the **Simple Move to Location** function on actors that does not have support to execute it.

So you must set the target and also set the projectile to be **HOMING**.

So you set the **Homing Target** and the **Homing Acceleration Magnetude**.

**Event to target setting and to defining aspects of the projectile (Projectile Blueprint):**

[image]

This last part is optional, as it sets the rotation of the projectile so that it points to the target. If your projectile is a sphere, there is no need to put it.

**Event to set the rotation of the projectile (Projectile Blueprint):**

[image]

**Links that helped me:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyNzsbTpGqg

https://forums.unrealengine.com/community/community-content-tools-and-tutorials/48896-homing-missile?77586-Homing-missile=

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/239188/rinterp-to-doesnt-slowly-change-character-rotation.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCkFqSOdw6M&